# Can I recover an incomplete .wav file?

Tags: wav, recovery

I've got a Behringer X32 mixer. I'm using it's built-in recording capability to write a .wav file to an USB drive. Today, I got an incomplete recording: the file on the USB drive shows up as 0 kb size. This usually happens when I remove the USB drive without stopping the recording first [*].

The mixer writes to the USB drive every second or so, so the audio should all be there. The file header just hasn't been finalized, so the computer doesn't know how large the file should be.

Is there a way to recover the audio?

*: I know, I shouldn't be doing that. But I'm sure I pressed Stop, then waited ~5 seconds before removing the drive. It's happened before so I'm pretty careful with the recordings these days. Shit still happens...

Comment: This seems to work for a lot of people https://youtu.be/lw5zBkoWAg8

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem. After pressing Stop, the 'access' light for the USB drive keeps blinking for ~5 seconds. I may have removed the drive too soon.

Comment: I am running into a similar problem with my Zoom H1N recorder. The battery fell out a few times in the midst of a few recordings, so I have about four hours of recordings, but my recording programmes won't open them. I'm using Windows, so the WavFix file won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that the WAV header has not been created correctly. If you are working on a Mac then you can try this application which I wrote to fix broken WAV files. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofzrbiqebut05zk/fixwav?dl=0

Also this is the methodology I used.

Comment: I haven't been able to test your app yet (I have to install OSX 10.12 first). When I open my file in iHex, it shows a file size of 0 bytes, so I can't use the method from the tutorial. I think I need to use a raw disk editor...

Comment: It sounds like you probably lost the file in the filesystem buffers rather than the application buffer. If that is the case, then you may not be able to recover it at all unfortunately. Usually recoverable files actually have some data associated with them on disk.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google came up with using Audacity to 'Import Raw', then re-save as a .WAV.
Untested.

Comment: I tried that, pointed at the 0kb file to import. Didn't get the file. I think the issue is that the header is written with a file length of 0, and at the end of the  recording this is overwritten with the correct length.

Answer (score 0):

if you turn off the mixer with out press the stop the file created is 0 KB  because is not closed. but the data are still in the usb disk
what do i do to recover this files:
I use in the command chkdsk /f under the disk drive letter ex: D:\chkdsk /F

or use this style:
Chkdsk Command Syntax
chkdsk [volume:] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L:size] [/perf] [/scan] [/?]

this will create a hidden folder named FOUND.000
and inside this folder you get all orphan files in order
FILE0000.CHK FILE0001.CHK

1. first to be able to see the files under explorer you have to check in foldr options Show hidden files
   2 you change the extention to wav  ( FILE0000.CHK to FILE0000.wav)
   this will not be playble  for some audio programms but will play  with VLC player. [www.videolan.org](http://www.videolan.org)

I hope you this will help you and anyone have the same problem
good luck with your recordings

last checked

To open these files in soundforge or any audio editor
select open RAW file format (no matter the extention) this will prompt you to add the sample rate and sample type . then the file is ready for any use.
:)